# simple Iframe in javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables, iframe

I am trying to iframe google.com i have tried dozens of combinations but the page keeps coming up blank.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var urlPath=http://google.com;
document.write('<iframe scrolling="yes" height="350" width ="350" src="'+urlPath+'"><\/iframe>');



</script>
```

Comment: Use a browser console to find javascript errors; This page was definitely generating errors, and you would have noticed the url was not in quotes

Comment: Don't use document.write. Use something as document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML('<iframe stuff') or create the iframe as element in JavaScript and use appendchild. First example I found: (first post has an error) http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=193427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var urlPath='http://google.com';
```

Just fix the variable value.

Comment: Its not blank, Google just doesnt allow their page to be shrunk down that much; the search bar is hidden way beyond the bounds of your iframe. EDIT: You can't use google in iframe; google will not allow you to load their page in an iframe; their server sends out an same-origins header, meaning only a site on google.com could load google.com in an iframe.

Comment: It is not that, Just any website, really it is in the core of web technologies and web browsers to prevent cross sites scripting. However, including any page in an iframe, abstractly, without change of the included page contents, is not cross site scripting. simply <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> will works fine and it will load Google in the iframe.

Comment: No it wont. Amazon loads fine, Google does not because Google sends out same-origin headers. XSS is prevented by not allowing Javascript to manipulate the contents of an iframe that are not the same domain, not preventing the loading of the frame content. http://jsfiddle.net/thundercracker/3f6Ks/

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz
Wonderful! I did not believed it unless I tried it on a local HTML file! Thank you for this valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

Google does indeed not load in an iframe(same origin restriction) Google has different ways for adding their searchbox and/or search results to your website. (search for google api)

And to give an example to what I commented in the question:
And if you must use JavaScript instead of html to get the iframe in your page I would suggest using code like the following:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src='http://yahoo.com';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has errors in it. See this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davew9999/JqHG9/

```
var urlPath = "http://www.google.com";
document.write('<iframe scrolling="yes" height="350" width ="350" src="' + urlPath + '"></iframe>');​
```

Not sure why you are doing in in JavaScript you could just do

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" height="350" width ="350" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

One thing to note, http://www.google.com won't load in an iFrame, as mentioned in the comments by Greg Rozmarynowycz, Google don't allow you to load it in an iFrame that isn't hosted by Google. Change the src to http://www.amazon.com to see that the code works.

Comment: Google sends out same-origin header; you can't load it in an iFrame that is in a page not hosted by Google.

Comment: Thanks for the info, referenced your comment in the answer